# Recursive deletion of files (bash)

Tags: bash, files, recursive

I'm familiar with how I would tackle this with PHP, however I'd like to get some more practice with bash scripting.

The task is to delete all files in a folder, which itself contains subfolders (with files).  The files would typically be .pdf (or some variant: PDF, Pdf, pDf, ect), however there may occasionally be other file types including extensions unknown to me at this time.

Here's what I have so far.  It echoes the filename, but if I issue rm $i, the system returns file not found on each file.

```
for i in `ls -bRC1 /foo/temp_folders/* ` ; do echo $i ; rm $i ; done
```

How would I force the absolute path when issuing rm $i?

Comment: Is there some reason why you wouldn't just use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Zoredache... why not:
`find /foo/temp_folders/ -type f -iname * -exec rm {} +`

Edit: changed the trailing \; to + for performance as noted [here](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2009/05/find-exec-vs-xargs.html)

Comment: I'd uprate you, but I don't have the mojo just yet - thanks for the response.

Comment: I wouldnt go with -exec rm {} + but rather simply with -delete -> it's much faster than constantly calling Linux's exec. The other day I had to delete tons of files and tried both, -delete option came out as absolute winner

Comment: Nifty, I didn't realize find even had a -delete option... I'll have to remember that one.

Answer (score 1):

find -exec would be slow on large number of files. I would suggest:

```
find /foo/temp_folders -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: I'd uprate you, but I don't have the mojo just yet - thanks for the response.

Comment: Actually, this is a good point, and not one I usually have to consider.  I found an interesting article that compares "-exec {} \;" to "-exec {} +" to "| xargs" here: http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2009/05/find-exec-vs-xargs.html